# When sharing an image with Intent, it gives an error when converting from byte[] to Uri

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent, uri

I have an application that uses API. I'm using the code below to share the image I got from the API.

```
byte[] byte;
final Bitmap[] bitmap = new Bitmap[1];
Glide.with(FilmActivity.this)
      .asBitmap()
      .load(imageLink)
      .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
           @Override
           public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                 bitmap[0] = resource;
                 byte = getBytes(bitmap[0]);
            }
           @Override
           public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

           }
});
```

```
private byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

I am using the following code to share byte[] type data.

```
try {
     Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, name);
     String s = new String(byte, "UTF-8");
     Uri uri = Uri.parse(s);
     sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
     sendIntent.setType("image/*");
     sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it doesn't work. I get the following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1677)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4544)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4905)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4873)
 at com.example.filmler.activity.FilmActivity$4.onClick(FilmActivity.java:205)
```

Comment: Write the bytes to a file. Use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()` to get a `Uri` for that file to use with `ACTION_SEND`. And use the actual MIME type, not a wildcard (`image/*`).

Comment: I didn't understand how to do it. Is there any code you can show as an example? I would be glad if you help.

Comment: [This sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/vFINAL/PdfProvider) (and [its Kotlin equivalent](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/vFINAL/PdfProvider)) demonstrate copying bytes to a file and using that file with `FileProvider`. In my case, the bytes are a PDF stored as an asset, and I use `ACTION_VIEW` instead of `ACTION_SEND`. However, it is fairly close to what you need. Those samples are covered in [this section](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-005.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).

Answer (score 0):

### Why are converting it to byte and sharing?

---

Why do you want to convert it? You can just save the bitmap like this:

```
String location = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap,new Random().nextInt(), null);
```

And then you can pass it to the intent like this:

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(location));
```

### Edit

---

If you do not want to save it on the device, you can do it this way.

1. Save the bitmap to cache.

```
File cacheDir = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();
File f = new File(cacheDir, "pic");

try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
            f);
    pic.compress(
            Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
            100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

2. Get the image and share it.

```
File cacheDir = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();
File f = new File(cacheDir, "pic");
```

3. Add it to intent

```
Uri uri = fromFile(f);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Comment: When you do it this way, the picture is saved to the device. I want to do it without interfering with the device.

Comment: can you try saving in on cache?

Comment: yes. sure and let me know if anything goes wrong